# How to store a multi-dimensional array in shared preferences using putStringSet in android?

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, sharedpreferences

This code is giving me error when I try to save the data in `shared preference` using `putStringSet`

please, let me know where I am doing wrong.

I am doing this as:

```
 public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
String[][] my_date;
    my_date = new String[][] {
            {"14","26"},
            {"12","16","24","27"},
            {"17"},
            {"8","13","18"},
            {"14"},
            {},
            {"29"},
            {"15","18"},
            {},
            {"2","3","6","8","23"},
            {"4","6","24"},
            {}
    };
   SharedPreferences pref = arg0.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    Set<String> myStrings = pref.**getStringSet**("my_date", new HashSet<String>());
                myStrings.add("Another string");
           editor.putStringSet("myStrings", myStrings);
           editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: What's you project's minimum sdk level? That method was introduced in Honeycomb(11).

Comment: i am using jelly bean 4.1

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 1): android.content.SharedPreferences#getStringSet" this is the error which is coming when i am using this code

Comment: Change the minimum sdk level in the manifest to 11 if you want to use that method.

Comment: android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" will i change this to 11

Comment: No, under the `uses-sdk` tag you should have `android:minSdkVersion="11"`. After you change this rebuild the project.